# How to copy/duplicate rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hello I have table with `ID,LongID,Categoty,Priority` columns and sample data like this:

```
ID     LongID     Category  Priority
------------------------------------
218     2432     301        1
222     2445     301        2
205     2416     301        3
214     2425     302        1
  5     1079     302        2
152     2388     302        3
143     2382     303        1
 89     2263     303        2
126     2375     303        3
```

I am building a duplicate function, ex: if I currently in category 301 and press duplicate I will find the next available Category ID (Category max)+1 that mean 304 and copy all rows from categoty 301 to 304

```
    ID     LongID     Category  Priority
    218     2432     301        1
    222     2445     301        2
    205     2416     301        3
    214     2425     302        1
    5       1079     302        2
    152     2388     302        3
    143     2382     303        1
    89      2263     303        2
    126     2375     303        3
    218     2432     304        1 <-new 304
    222     2445     304        2<-new 304
    205     2416     304        3<-new 304
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily using `INSERT..SELECT` syntax.

```
DECLARE @newCat INT
SELECT @newCat = COALESCE(MAX(Category),0)+1 FROM YourTable

INSERT INTO YourTable (ID, LongID, Category, Priority)
SELECT ID, LongID, @newCat, Priority
FROM YourTable WHERE Category = 301
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (ID, LongID, Category, Priority)
SELECT ID, LongID, @newCat, Priority
FROM YourTable WHERE Category = your_id
```